# How solve the problem "Unknown encoding format" in brackets

Tags: javascript, html, css, brackets

How to resolve the problem of the image.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't belong on StackOverflow. It isn't directly code related. I suggest finding a different place to post this problem.

Comment: show code to reproduce, vote close - as no context as to where this was even called from.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "UTF8 Converter" extension -- just open File > Extension Manager and search for "UTF."

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVE THE problem "Unknown encoding format" in brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3zf1.jpg)

- WHAT YOU NEED TO DO IS CHANGE THE "SELECT END OF LINE SEQUENCE" FROM **CRLF** TO **LF**.
- THEN ENSURE THAT YOUR DOCUMENT OPENS AND CLOSES WITH THE ENCODING UTF-8.

Comment: THIS IS FOR VS CODE

Comment: Hi, please edit your answer so that it does not like you are screaming (avoid unnecessary uppercase)